# Unable to use scraperapi with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use the scraperapi with selenium. It runs fine when I use it with python requests with the following code.

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://scraperapi:my_api_key@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001",
  "https": "http://scraperapi:my_api_key@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001"
}

r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/ip', proxies=proxies, verify=False)

print(r.text)
```

It returns the proxy IP with the above code.

But it returns my original IP when I try with following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
proxy = "http://api.scraperapi.com?api_key=my_api_key&render=true" 

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)

url = 'http://httpbin.org/ip'
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Did you find out how to do this, I'm trying to setup my scraperapi proxy with selenium and node, and I can't get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

According to ScraperAPI's own guides, the easiest way seems to be using `selenium-wire` instead of plain selenium

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
proxy_options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': f'http://scraperapi:{API_KEY}@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=proxy_options)
driver.get("http://httpbin.org/ip")
```

https://www.scraperapi.com/quick-start-guides/python-selenium-scraper/

Comment: Just remember that you will get charged for a lot of requests as your browser will be interchanging a lot of info between it and the server.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working very well -- the page does not load propery when using seleniumwire_options, is there other work around?